# present value, continously compounded

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling

> Compute the present value of a payment of 10 000 Euro after 3 years, if the continuously compounded interest rate in the first year ist 4%, in the second year 6%, and in the third year 5%.

For a continously compounded model we write: $P_0= P(t)e^{-rt} $
So the present value must be $ P_0= \frac{10 000}{e^{0.15}} =8607.08 $ Euro

Is that the correct formula/way for this exercise? I´m not sure..

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: It's fine, although the brevity of your solution makes it difficult to see if you understand everything perfectly.  To test your understanding, you might try the following:  if you change the interest from continuous compounding to annual, but at the same rates, how would you solve it?  And if you  change the problem so that the 4% applies for the first 6 months, the 6% applies to the following 12 months, and the 5% applies for the final 18 months, how would your solution change?

Comment: Annual compounding with the formula $P_0= \frac{P(t)}{(1+\frac{r}{m})^{mt}}$. 

So i get for anual compounding with the interestrate in my first post: $P_0= \frac{10 000}{(1+ 0.05/12)^{12}*(1+ 0.04/12)^{12}*(1+ 0.06/12)^{12}}$

For annual compounding with your changed problem i get the formula: $P_0= \frac{1000}{(1+0.05/12)^{12*1.5}(1+0.06/12)^{12*1}(1+0.04/12)^{12*0.5}}$


For continously compounding with your changed problem i get the formula:

$P_0=\frac{1000}{e^{-0.5*1.5+0.6*1+0.4*0.5}}$


Is this right @BarrySmith ?

Comment: When you use $m=12$, you are assuming that the rates were given as nominal monthly rates.  If you assume they are annual effective rates, you should use m=1.   Otherwise, yes, it looks like you get it pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see it's correct:

$$
P_3 = P_0 \underbrace{\cdot e^{r_1} \cdot e^{r_2} \cdot e^{r_3}}_\text{one factor per year} = P_0 \cdot e^{r_1 + r_2 + r_3} = P_0 \cdot e^{0.15} \\
P_0 = P_3 \cdot e^{-0.15} \approx 8607.08€
$$